# Migrate contract-first SOAP-RPC service to Java

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

we currently have a problem with supporting a legacy API offered via SOAP-RPC. The current service is exposed via a PHP extension and now we would like to offer it via Java. Switching to a Java implementation would mean a SOAP-WS service since we could not find a way to expose SOAP-RPC in Java.

The facts:

- Our Java application runs as a servlet in Tomcat
- document style "rpc" is not supported in Apache CXF, leads to arrays described differently
- Apache CXF only supports JAX-B and not JAX-RPC.

Is there any way / tutorial to explain the writing of a SOAP-RPC service with current technology like Spring-WS or Apache CXF?

Comment: Spring WS is document driven only and not RPC style. To work with the legacy RPC style of things you would have to revert to the very old JAX-RPC way of doing things. You probably want to google for a jax-rpc tutorial on the web.

Comment: Thank you. I managed now to import the old wsdl using the wsdl java import and now there are the needed primitives for the arrays. Now both returned SOAP and descriptive wsdl look the same as prior to migration (Although we had to add an XSLT transformation in the Apache CXF hook to get the <result>name_of_array</result> prior to the array.)